# Windows shell-extension manager?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-registry, context-menu, shell-extensions

Is there a tool to remove a shell-extension? I was able to remove some context-menus using RegEdit but doing a search in the registry for others have failed.

Answer (score 8):

A great tool that makes removing (or just disabling) shell-extensions easier is [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html). Use the *mark* options and sort on the various columns to help quickly cut through the clutter.

As well, [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) displays shell-extensions in the *Explorer* tab. Again, use the *hide* options to reduce false-positives.

If you are specifically trying to get rid of a context-menu, it may not actually be a shell-extensions; in which case, try [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) which makes it easy to manage such items.

Comment: These tools seem to be ones I should be able to use but they are still not finding the menu entries I want to remove. I wonder if  these menu entries are "injected" when Windows runs instead of being read from repositories like the registry?

Comment: It may not be a shell-extensions. I added another tool for that case. If that doesn't help, then you may want to give some information on the specific context-menus you are trying to get rid of.

Comment: I have several. One is Catalyst Control Center which was installed by the gfx card. Another is 'Compress and email' from WinRar.

Comment: The CCC should be in Autoruns, just search for `ATI` in the *Explorer* tab, then uncheck the two or three entries. Do the same for WinRAR (or just unselect the option *inside* WinRAR*).

Comment: Updated link to Autoruns: [Autoruns for Windows v14.06](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns). Autoruns did the job quite well for me just minutes ago. (It is too early to conclude anything about potential unintended consequences, though.)